How does the fracture between fields of knowledge and their respective philosophies come to be?
Let F be a subset of knowledge, PF its respective philosophy, and P the set of all philosophy. What is the genealogy of the fracture between F and PF?
I recognize this is a broad question, so maybe trying to tackle some sub-questions might help, e.g.:

Does F ⊆ PF always hold true, by virtue of P being a meta-discipline?
Practically speaking, does F or PF get created first? (feel free to use any F as example)
Are there any elements in P who can't "emancipate" themselves as F ?


Indeed it could be defined or said so as was the actual historical development shows, such as the field of science was originally just called natural philosophy even in recent Newton's time...
